# Image won't render before setTimeout(0) call

Tags: javascript, sleep, event-loop

Reference code:

```
function sleep( sleepDuration ){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* do nothing */ } 
}

function submit_answer(label) {
  let image = get_node('img.to_label')
  let size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)
  image.src = `http://via.placeholder.com/${size}x${size}`
  setTimeout(sleep.call(this, 1000), 0)
}
```

`submit_answer` is called from a click handler.

**Desired function:** the image is rendered, and the user is forced to wait 1 second before interacting with the page in any way.

**Actual function**: the user waits 1 second, and the image loads.

I thought `setTimeout` would put `sleep` on a queue - I was hoping that the image would be rendered before they were made to wait. How can I force the image to render, and then force the user to wait?

Comment: **1.** `setTimeout(sleep.call(this, 1000), 0)` probably doesn't do what you think. **2.** Don't use that stupid sleep function, it's a waste of user's CPU.

Comment: You would use the onload event, but using that sleep is a bad idea.... its better name would be "freeze" or "lock up" since that is all it does.

Comment: That sleep function accomplishes exactly what I want from a UI perspective. Not every application fits into the same mold - you're right though, in general it's an awful idea.

@AlexanderO'Mara please be more kind to others in the future. You can explain without calling things "stupid".

Comment: You *want* the UI to lock up? Do you also want your users to hate you? Locking up a browser is a great way to accomplish that. No really, there is no reason to ever do that, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)** and **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)** take a function **reference** or code **as a string** (but, don't do that) as their first argument. Your code:

```
setTimeout(sleep.call(this, 1000), 0)
```

passes an actual function invocation of `sleep` and that's why you get sleep first (it's being called immediately) and the image load second. The return value from the function invocation is what winds up getting used as the function reference, but `sleep` doesn't return a value, so `undefined` winds up being passed to the timer and so nothing happens when the timer expires. The line would need to be:

```
setTimeout(function(){ sleep.call(this, 1000) }, 0)
```

so that a function reference would correctly be the first argument and the call to `sleep` wouldn't happen immediately.

From the docs:

> **Syntax:**
>
> var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(**function**[, delay, param1, param2, ...]);
>
> var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(**function**[, delay]);
>
> var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(**code**[, delay]);
>
> NOTE: **code**
>   An alternative syntax that allows you to include a string instead of a function, which is compiled and executed when the timer expires. This syntax is not recommended for the same reasons that make using eval() a security risk.

Also, setting a timer delay of `0` will never happen. The JavaScript runtime is synchronous and will only run the callback function specified in the timer when it has nothing else to do. As a result, you can never really know for absolute certain what the delay will wind up being. Think of the delay as the minimum amount of time you can expect to wait for your function to run. Having said that, I read somewhere that there was an absolute minimum of 16ms due to the latency between the JavaScript runtime and the browser's WebAPI.

---

Now, you are going to need to be able to trap the moment that the image actually gets rendered and that can be accomplished with **[`.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)**.

Then, what you need to do is much simpler. You set your timer to start as soon as the image has finished loading and that is done by setting up a callback on the image's `load` event.

But, your code does nothing to prevent the user from interacting with the page, so you'll need to add a "mask" over the page that prevents interaction.

I've made the timer 3 seconds and given the mask a grey color in the snippet below to show the effect better.

```js
var mask = document.getElementById("mask");
    
function startRender() {
  // Rendering started, run callback when next render occurs
  requestAnimationFrame(rendered);  
}

function rendered() {
  sleep(3000);  // Render complete
}

// Nothing happens until the image fires off its load event...
document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("load", function(){
  // Run callback when next render occurs
  requestAnimationFrame(startRender);
});

function preventKeystrokes(evt){
  preventDefault();
}

function sleep(duration){
  mask.classList.remove("hidden");  // Show mask to prevent interactions
  window.addEventListener("keydown", preventKeystrokes); // prevent keystrokes
  // Count to three
  setTimeout(function(){
    mask.classList.add("hidden");  // Remove mask
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", preventKeystrokes); // Enable keyboard
  }, duration);
}
```

```css
#mask { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:99; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6); width:100%; height:100%; }
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<button>Try to click me!</button>
<img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hvi/uploads/image_file/image_attachment/30466/STSCI-H-p1801a-m-2000x1692.png" alt="big image">
<div id="mask" class="hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Whoops - I guess I was thinking "bind", not "call". Thanks for that! Adding a load event leads to the same behavior, though. Try changing the img src - the event handler runs before rendering the image.

Comment: Also, that allows keyboard interaction. I'm trying to completely freeze the window.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson Answer updated to address that (although that really wasn't your question).

Comment: @ChrisAnderson Answer updated again. You can use `.requestAnimationFrame()` to trap when the render is complete. See updated code.

Comment: It was part of my question: "the user is forced to wait 1 second before interacting with the page in any way."

Comment: @ChrisAnderson Well, that's not a question, that's a statement. And, since you didn't have any of that code in your original question, it reads like that's not the part you are inquiring about. At any rate, my answer covers it, so please up vote it and mark it as "the" answer if it satisfies what you were looking for.